# Jolt: Concat of two strings in array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

iam trying to concat the two string from the array and have tried the in jolt. i couldn't get out put:

input is:

```json
[
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "setFrstNm": "John"
  },
  {
    "setLastNm": "Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "set1FrstNm": "sam"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "set1LastNm": "jim"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "set2FrstNm1": "jun"
  },
  {
    "set2LastNm1": "san",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

Desired output should be:

```json
[
  {
    
    "setfullname": "John jammy"
     "policy": "Name",
  },
  
  {
    "set1fullname": "sam jim",
    "policy": "Name",
  },
  {
    "set2fullname": "jun san",
    "policy": "Name",
  },
  
]
```

Shift that i am tried for one set

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "setfullname": "=concat(@(1,setFrstNm),' ',@(1,setLastNm))"
        "policy": "Name"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan please review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to determine the grouping criteria in order to form upcoming objects will depend on

```json
[
  { // group by Last/Frs removed key names 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*Last*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1).&(1,1)fullname" // in &(1,1) : the first 1 represents going 1 level up the tree
                                                 //             the second 1 represents the replacement for the 1st asterisk 
        },
        "*Frs*": {
          "@": "@2,policy.&(1,1).&(1,1)fullname"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // concatenate the pairs by their key names respectively 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[#2].&",
          "$1": "[#2].policy" // deliver back the policy attribute to those objects
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, I have 3 set of full name and all are different..   "setfullname":    "set1fullname":       "set2fullname": ....

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, can you please check and provide the inputs?

Comment: ...If you check my  expected output.... we have  3 set of full name , we need to split the full name based the fullname output.[
  {
    
    "setfullname": "John jammy"
     "policy": "Name",
  },
  
  {
    "set1fullname": "sam jim",
    "policy": "Name",
  },
  {
    "set2fullname": "jun san",
    "policy": "Name",
  },
  
]

Comment: i got it @Barbaros Özhan, can you please provide your input and how to get 3 different set full name . That will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much  @Barbaros Özhan..  Just one last query.... if we have name like this ...setfullname": "setfullname1": "setfullname2"... how can we add it in shift....

Comment: We start with six names(three of them fname and others are surnames) in the current case, but now you're asking about concatenated names, how and where, excuse me not clear. Can you please ask a new question to state what input you have and how kind of conversion you need ? @ManimaranDhandapani